# hosted sharepoint backup

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-designer, backup

I have a hosted sharepoint site that I want to make a backup of

Currently I have a script that connects to the site (and subsites) via webdav and downloads all the documents. This however doesn't help me much for information stored in lists

Is there a way to automate downloading all the information in a sharepoint site including data stored in lists programmatically?

I have sharepoint designer 2007 but i don't see any option in there to backup data or to have it do so via a command promt

Thanks so much

Crash